# Android Toolbar: Click on the imageButton does not stays the same

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-imagebutton, android-selector

`enter code here`I have found similar questions on stack overflow but could not figure out the solution. I am newbie to android. I have a toolbar and I am trying to implement a "Like" button on the toolbar. Basically in viewPager's view I show user some quotation and if user like it they can click on the like button on toolbar. Later on, I am planning to implement the functionality that user would be able to go to his "Likes" quotations. I have following questions issues:

- 1) Is this the right way to do it? I mean should I put a imagebutton
  on toolbar and then handle clicks?
- 2) Right now when I click on the "Like" button it changes to Dark
  heart but then it comes back to border heart right away. I want it to
  stay dark until user clicks back on it.
- 3) Any link to similar example would be very helpful.

And toolbar:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/quote_reader_toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:titleTextColor="#ffffff">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnLike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_feed_action"

         />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Finally the c ode to handle Imagebutton Click:

```
   public void addListenerOnButton() {

    likeButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLike);

    likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Like bUTTON pRESSED");

        }

    });

}

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_favorite_border_black_24dp" /> <!--     default -->
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, to your second question, no, it's not the right way. Why? Because the `state_pressed="true"` option means that you press the button and KEEP PRESSING IT, once you stop pressing it just changes to the default state.

How to do it then? You can do it easy from code changing the background resource at the onClick method like this:

```
YOURBUTTON.setBackgroundResource(YOUR_IMAGE);
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Well this works partially, I want it to revert back to default state if user presses it again. Also this kinnda make "selector" unnecessary. I was thinking that selector does this as in my code above.

Comment: If you want it to revert its as easy as, on the "onclick" method, get the image resource name and "if it's one, change to two", "if it's two, change it to one". I dont know if you understood. Anyway you can try to change the state_pressed="true" for an "state_checked"

Comment: May I ask which solution you used? I'll modify the answer depending on that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
 public void addListenerOnButton() {

    likeButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnLike);

    likeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Like bUTTON pRESSED");
            likeButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp);
        }

    });

}
```

or you can also create a shape button_pressed.xml

For example

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="@color/grey" />

    <stroke
        android:width="xxdp"
        android:color="@color/grey" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="xx dp"
        android:left="xx dp"
        android:right="xx dp"
        android:top="xx dp" />

</shape>
```

and then

```
    Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_pressed);

    likeButton.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `ImageButton` with `Toolbar` as it's root view

```
likeButton = (ImageButton) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.btnLike);
```

Comment: Well this works partially, I want it to revert back to default state if user presses it again. Also this kinnda make "selector" unnecessary. I was thinking that selector does this as in my code above.